# How do I edit the text on a button if the button is in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, button, tkinter

Hi i'm using python tkinter and have created a list of buttons. I have been trying to program it so if you press a button the text on it changes to an X or an O (for the game tic tac toe). I tried using button["text"] = "text" but it just comes up with an error. Here's the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

bclick = True

buttons =  [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",]
button_list = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",]
def make_button(n, row, col):
    button_list[n] = Button(tk,text=" ",bg='gray',fg='white',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:ttt(buttons, n))
    button_list[n].grid(row=row,column=col, sticky=S+N+E+W)
    button_list[n] = n

a = 0
B = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
C = [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
while a != 9:
    b=B[a]
    c=C[a]
    make_button(a, b, c)
    a+=1

def ttt(buttons, n):
     global bclick
     if buttons[n] == " " and bclick == True:
         buttons[n] = "X"
         button_list[n]["text"] = "X"
         bclick = False
     elif buttons[n] == " " and bclick == False:
          buttons[n] = "O"
          bclick = True
```

Error from comment:

> File "C:\Users\Eva Morris\Documents\computing\Tic-Tac-Toe.py", line 28, in ttt button_list[n]["text"] = "X" TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What's the errore message that you are getting?

Comment: It comes up with an error ... do you mind sharing the _exact error message_

Comment: @Patrick Artner    The error is:   File "C:\Users\Eva Morris\Documents\computing\Tic-Tac-Toe.py", line 28, in ttt
    button_list[n]["text"] = "X"
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code - you overwrite the Button-instance with an integer:

```
def make_button(n, row, col):
    button_list[n] = Button(tk,text=" ",bg='gray',fg='white',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:ttt(buttons, n))
    button_list[n].grid(row=row,column=col, sticky=S+N+E+W)
    button_list[n] = n # here you are assigning an INT to button_list[n]
```

On an `int` the acces via `["text"]` is notsupported. Thats about what the error message tells you. Thats why providing us with the exact error *matters*.